# Desktop Environment in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, window-managers

I want to create a very simple window manager for Ubuntu using Ruby. Where should I start?
I am somewhat familiar with Qt (from when I used to use C++), but I don't mind using other frameworks.

Comment: Because it's sexy and a pleasure to work with?

Comment: @Fábio Batista, Oh, how very right you are... +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this great presentation, presenting several toolkit alternatives. It's in Portuguese, but it should not be hard to understand the toolkit names and screnshots :)

http://www.slideshare.net/guest2a3a90/ruby-no-desktop-marcelo-castellani